# How to get the content of text area when content is not shown in html?

Tags: python, lxml, python-requests

I have a text area on a webpage that is hidden until a checkbox is clicked. It is full of xml which I would like to use. I am able to get that html anyway. The content of the text area does not appear in the html though, even when it is clicked in my browser. Is there a way for me to access that data?

```
<header>View XML</header>
  <section>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column-left label"></div>
      <div class="column-right xmldraft">
        <textarea id="xmldraft" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" rows="4" type="text" style="height: 300px;"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

I am getting the text area with the following code

```
import requests
from lxml import html

payload = {'pass': 'PASSWORD', 'user': 'USER','submit':'go'}## Log in info

r = requests.get("http://WEBSITE.com/s2/job.php?orderID=ABCDEF&jobID=WXYZ", params=payload) ## Get page

tree = html.fromstring(r.text) ## break down webpage into parseable data

rawdata=tree.xpath(".//*[@id='xmldraft']")  ## Get text area
```

but when I try any of the following I get no results

```
>>>rawdata
[<TextareaElement 10ab55c00 name=None>]
>>>rawdata[0].text
>>>rawdata[0].text_content()
''
>>>rawdata[0].value
''
>>>rawdata[0].tag
'textarea'
```

**Edit:** It seems the javascript which populates it is partially written here:

```
function update_XML() {
  var Rserializer = new ONEGEEK.GSerializer();
  var RserializedXML = Rserializer.serialize(website.job, 'MyRequest');
  var serializer = new ONEGEEK.GSerializer();
  var serializedXML = serializer.serialize(website.XMLResult, 'MyResult');
  $('#xmldraft').css("height", 300);
  $('#xmldraft').val(RserializedXML);
  var txt = $("#xmldraft");
  txt.val(txt.val() + "\n\n\n");
  txt.val(txt.val() + serializedXML);
}
```

GSerializer doesn't have a source, so the above seems to be passing the data in.

**I'm not really sure how to find a deeper source, so I'm just going to use selenium**

Comment: look through the rest of the page's source code and see how the XML is being added to the textarea - it's probably loaded using JavaScript and an AJAX request to a server. In that case, you'll need to approach this in a new way.

Comment: Either the content is stored in an hidden element of the part somewhere else, in which case you can fetch this other element. Either it is loaded in AJAX in which case you can try to parse the URL called by the AJAX part. If you fail in both try selenium to have something to interpret JS an issue actions on the page.

Comment: I took a look and it seems that it is called from a bunch of scripts and nowhere present in the captured html. I was hoping not to need to use selenium, as it's much slower, but from the looks of it that may be my only option. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use following or similar locators to identify the element:

```
area = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#textarea")
```

Then you need to use following JS method to get the value of area:

```
value = driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].value;", area)
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.